# K&R2 solution to exercise 1-18 (discarding trailing whitespace and empty lines)

Tags: beginner, c, strings, io

Recently I have started learning C++ and I decided to learn C along the way to improve my understanding of how computers work. For C I am using "The C Programming Language Book" by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.

The exercise in question is to print all input lines disregarding trailing whitespace and empty lines.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_BLANKS 5

int main()
{
    int c; /*holds current char to be printed*/
    int* wsbuffer; /*buffer to hold possible trailing whitespace*/
    int buffer_size; /*size of wsbuffer*/
    int nws; /*number of whitespaces in buffer*/
    int nonempty; /*0 if current line is empty, 1 else*/
    int i; /*for loop*/
    nonempty  = nws = 0;
    buffer_size = MAX_BLANKS;
    wsbuffer = (int*) malloc(buffer_size*sizeof(int));

    while (EOF != (c=getchar()))
    {
        if (c==' ' || c=='\t')
        {
            ++nws;
            if (nws>buffer_size)
            { 
                buffer_size *=2;
                wsbuffer = (int*) realloc(wsbuffer,buffer_size*sizeof(int));
            }
            wsbuffer[nws-1] = c;
        }
        else if (c=='\n')
        {
            if (nonempty==1) {
                putchar(c);
                nws = nonempty = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nonempty = 1;
            for (i=0;i<nws;++i)
                putchar(wsbuffer[i]);
            nws = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    free(wsbuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this using `gcc -std=c90 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to adhere to the ISO protocol used by the book. It compiled fine with no warnings.

I deliberately set `MAX_BLANKS` to `5` to test the code. I tested a few cases (empty lines, lines with only space, spaces at first etc) and the result seemed okay.

Since memory allocation is not yet covered in the book, I'd particularly like it if someone could take a look and let me know if I have any issues particularly with memory leaking or something. Of course, any other suggestions or improvements would be welcome!

Comment: Didja use a profiling tool? Those work well for discovering leaks.

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure what this is?

Comment: Bugs are to the debugger as performance is to the profiler.

Comment: @RichardBarker How do you use a profiler? I never figured out how.

Comment: Depends on the language and tool but it's mostly universal. visual studio has one built in and there are plenty of resources out there about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't cast the return value from `malloc` and family - provided there's a prototype in scope (which there is here, due to our `#include <stdlib.h>`), the `void*` result will convert to any pointer type.

Always check whether the returned pointer is a null pointer before using it:

```
wsbuffer = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof *wsbuffer);
if (!buffer) {
    fputs("Memory allocation failure\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Robust code needs to take extra care when using `realloc()`.  If we write something like `p = realloc(p, new_size);` then we have a problem when it fails - `p` is assigned null, and we have nothing pointing to the memory any more (i.e. a memory leak).  The usual pattern looks something like:

```
void *new_buf = realloc(wsbuffer, buffer_size * sizeof *wsbuffer);
if (!new_buf) {
    free(wsbuffer);
    fputs("Memory allocation failure\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
wsbuffer = new_buf;
```

---

Minor things:

- Instead of `c==' ' || c=='\t'`, we might consider `isspace(c)`, remembering that this test includes newlines and other whitespace.
- We can store whitespace in an array of `char` rather than `int`, since we never need to store `EOF` into that buffer.
- The logic might be simpler if use a larger buffer and read a whole line at a time.  Then we just overwrite the start of the last whitespace found in the line, and print it.  That's likely a bit more efficient than our character-at-a-time operation, too.

Comment: Thanks Toby! I didn't get the last part about the larger buffer? Do you mean just storing all input and printing them out when I encounter `\n` or `EOF`?

Comment: Might be better to make `isspace(c)` a link to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/

Comment: I meant that we should consider reading a whole line (using `fgets()` - **N.B. not `gets()`** which is irretrievably flawed), and then process and print the line before reading the next line.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't learn about fgets yet, I'll read up on it!

Comment: No need to rush; you can work your way through the book and then revisit earlier chapters and self-review your earlier work in the light of the later knowledge.  I find that a good learning technique.

Comment: OP's `getchar()` approach has an advantage over `fgets()`: it well handles reading/writing rare _null characters_.  With `fgets()`, those readily are lost.

Answer (score 5):

This is in addition to @TobySpeight review.

**Standard Symbolic Constants**
Since `stdlib.h` is included, you have access to [`EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status) which are standard macros implemented on all systems. These work in C++ as well as C. These are more [portable than `return 0` or `return 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867871/should-i-return-exit-success-or-0-from-main). Most modern C compilers will append `return 0;` so it really isn't necessary in this particular case. You may have noticed the use of `EXIT_FAILURE` in @TobySpeight answer.

**Sizeof in malloc and realloc**
A safer practice is to use what the variable points to rather than a specific type. This will allow you to change the type of the array without changing each `malloc` or `calloc`.

```
wsbuffer = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(*wsbuffer));
```

As @TobySpeight mentioned the return value of every memory allocation should be tested for `NULL`.

**Boolean Values**
Somewhere in the book you should find:

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

This might make the code more readable. The C standard has progressed; since the second version of the book was written there is an additional header file that can be used for Booleans, [`<stdbool.h>`](//stackoverflow.com/q/6118846).

**Programming Style**
Generally it is better to wrap operators in expressions in spaces to make the code more readable.

```
    for (i = 0; i < nws; ++i)

    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t')
```

For code maintenance reasons, a safer practice when using control constructs (loops, `if`, `else`) is to always enclose even a single statement within a block (`{`..`}`):

```
        for (i = 0; i < nws; ++i) {
            putchar(wsbuffer[i]);
        }
```

That reduces bugs introduced during code maintenance where a second line needs to be added within the control block.

**Variable Declarations**
When the book was written, all variables had to be declared at the top of the function. This isn't true anymore.

In C, as in C++, variables can be declared as they are needed. For instance a loop control variable such as `i` can be declared just before the loop.

Comment: "These are more portable than return 0 or return 1" That's not true, where did you get that idea from?

Comment: "This wasn't true when the second version of the book came out" This is wrong, the 2nd edition was published in 1988. It barely conforms to the C90 standard. It wasn't possible to declare variables anywhere until C99 in 1999.

Comment: @Lundin I have removed the the comment about the second version of the book. I'm looking for the reference about the portability, however, I believe it was an answer on stack overflow.

Comment: @Lundin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867871/should-i-return-exit-success-or-0-from-main

Comment: That's based on some subjective old crap from Unix `man` regarding portability to OpenVMS from 1977. Nothing in the C standard says that EXIT_FAILURE is more portable. Unless you are doing some dinosaur compatibility project as part of archaeology class, it doesn't matter which form you are using.

Comment: @Lundin I programmed in VAX 11 C (the original VMS). I also programed C on BSD Unix and Solaris (System 5 Unix).

Comment: `#define TRUE = 1` is plain wrong. `TRUE` will expand to `= 1` instead of `1`. Use `#define TRUE 1`instead, or `#include <stdbool.h>` for portable definitions.

Comment: @JL2210 you are correct, not enough coffee. Fixed